# How to undo an operation in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I accidentally applied a label on all the elements in a VOB.

This label points to the production code version.

How can I revert the operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is a non-UCM label (ie not an UCM baseline), you can move it (see [`cleartool mklabel` man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-41))

```
cleartool mklabel -replace -recurse -nc yourLabel
```

Do that in a view which selects the right version and your label will point to those.